# Dynamically filled Datagridview not able to show changed cell data (VB.NET)

Tags: vb.net, datagridview, dynamically-generated

It been a while since I've been working on a project... For the moment I'm stuck with a datagridview.

First of all I'm going to explain what I've set up:
 I have a standard form with two datagridviews.
 - The first datagrid shows all CI (collection off all sorts of Hardware)
 - The Second datagrid shows the details of the selected CI from the first datagrid.

Depending on what kind of CI is selected, the detail shows different fields.
This is a part of my code to fill my second datagrid:

```
MyInstance = Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetType(NameOfClass))
            dgvDetail.DataSource = Nothing
            dgvDetail.Columns.Clear()
            dgvDetail.DataSource = MyInstance.GetSpecific(nummer)
            dgvDetail.EditMode = DataGridViewEditMode.EditOnEnter
            MaakdgvDetailOp()
            For Each r As DataGridViewRow In dgvDetail.Rows
                For i As Int32 = 0 To dgvDetail.Columns.Count - 1
                    r.Cells(i).ReadOnly = False
                Next
            Next
```

I think it has something to do with DataPropertyName, but I don't know what...

I disabled the groupbox, but when I click on the edit button all becomes active and I can edit the data.
When I leave the changed field, the original data shows...

I have some images here :
After startup and selecting a CI:
http://users.telenet.be/JensCasier/PRG.JPG
Clicked on edit:
same link but: PRG2.JPG
Changed the name:
same link but: PRG3.JPG
Pressed Tab or just go to another focus:
same link but: PRG4.JPG

Comment: Please clarify what is the exact problem?

Comment: You can place image somewhere and give only link to your question.